# Undefined variable: $http_response_header

Tags: php

I am trying to get a ticker script working but I get

> Undefined variable: http_response_header

error. I googled and found out that $http_response_header is global and built into php then why do I get this error. I am using wamp with PHP 5.4 installed. Here is my code:

```
$url="https://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCCAD/money/ticker";
$json = @file_get_contents($url);

//check for errors
if (strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")) {
  // On success, decode JSON
  $data = json_decode($json);
```

Thanks
Ahmar

Comment: Where do you read that `$http_response_header` is global?

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `$http_response_header` is not global.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php  I would suggest using cURL instead anyway.

Comment: @Brad I am trying to get this ticker to work. But it uses http header response http://skybin.net/bitcoin-ticker-on-your-website/

Comment: Why do you `@` hide errors? Problem can come from here...

Comment: @AhmarAli You don't need to check the headers in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCCAD/money/ticker");

if( !empty($content) )
{
    $data = json_decode($content);

    if ( json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE ) 
    {
        die("incorrect data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer posted in [comments section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php#121250) for the variable in docs:

> Bear in mind this special variable is somehow protected and not populated in some situation when the peer server close the connection early on (ssl reset)
> => Undefined variable: http_response_header

> Should you want to cope with this situation:
>
> ```
> $headers = array('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request');
> !empty($htp_response_header) && $headers = $http_response_header;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if I understood what you wanted to do. I tested the below written code in php 5.5

Try it .

```
 <?php 
    function get_contents() {

      $url="https://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCCAD/money/ticker";
      $json =  file_get_contents($url);

      if(strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")){
        $data = json_decode($json);
            //you return $data 
            //return $data;

        var_dump($data);
      }

    }

    get_contents(); // call the function
```

if you don't like using that function :

```
   $url="https://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCCAD/money/ticker";
      $json =  file_get_contents($url);
      if(strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")){
        $data = json_decode($json);
        var_dump($data);
      }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I was using the third party API and there is SSL issue.

Download the cacert.pem file after add below line in your php.ini

curl.cainfo ='/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/cacert.pem'

openssl.cafile ='/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/cacert.pem'

Answer (score 0):

CURL and other related request wrappers use a "CA certificate" bundle extracted from Mozilla to validate Certificate Authorities. This bundle is refreshed from time to time and must be keep *semi* up to date. If it get too old you will start getting intermittent issues with `$http_response_header` not being available.

Download the [cacert.pem](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) file to the locations listed in your `php.ini`.

**Example**

```
curl.cainfo ='/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/cacert.pem'
openssl.cafile ='/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/cacert.pem'
```

Change `/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/cacert.pem` to match the path of where you saved the file.